# Bottomsheet Using Bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
var _vis;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body:  BlocProvider<FirstCounterBloc>(
        create: (context) => FirstCounterBloc(),
    child:
    BlocBuilder<FirstCounterBloc,int>(
        builder:(context,count){
          _vis=context;
          return  Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: MaterialButton(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(19.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.pinkAccent)),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Text(
                    "Press",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    showModalBottomSheet<FirstCounterBloc>(
                        context: _vis,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Baseline(
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      "Counter 1",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink,),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                                    Text(
                                      "${count}",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up,color: Colors.pink,size:20.0), onPressed: (){
                                      BlocProvider.of<FirstCounterBloc>(_vis).add(eventType.first);
                                    }
                                    ),

                                    ),

                                  ],
                                ),


                         );
                        });
```

I have bloc named FirstCounterBloc which is performing addition.
I am Looking for the solution of how to update the bottom sheet-like.
I am doing set state it's also not working.
Somehow I can call bloc event but can not update the state can anyone give any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Vishwesh, Try using StatefulBuilder within the showModalBottomSheet to make state changes available for modal.